# How to add the stock and the price of my products, in google search results?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have a multilingual eshop in wordpress, and I try to add, in google search results, the stock and the price of my products. 
I would like to ask is there any plugin to make this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after is called Rich Snippits which is structured data on your web page that tells Google specific information about your products. See https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll check it out!